# Is it possible to pass a ViewModel object encapsulating Person to a Create view but only receive a Person object from a POST Create action method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a domain model and a view model as follows:

**Domain Model:**

```
namespace MvcApplication1.Models
{
    public enum Sex { Male, Female };
    public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage="Please select either Female or Male.")]
        public Sex? Sex { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**View Model:**

```
namespace MvcApplication1.ViewModels
{
    public class HomeCreateVM
    {
        public HomeCreateVM()
        {
        }
        public HomeCreateVM(Person p)
        {
            Person = p;
            SelectList = p.Sex.GetSelectList();
        }
        public Person Person { get; set; }
        public SelectList SelectList { get; set; }

    }
}
```

The auxiliary extension method is defined as follows:

```
namespace MvcApplication1.Models
{
    public static class Utilities
    {
        public static SelectList GetSelectList<XXX>(this XXX? obj) where XXX : struct
        {
            var values = from XXX x in Enum.GetValues(typeof(XXX))
                         select new { Text = x.ToString(), Value = x };
            return new SelectList(values, "Value", "Text", obj);
        }
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var p = new Person();

    return View(new HomeCreateVM(p));
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Person hc)// the source of problem!
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)//always false!
    {
        TempData["status"] = hc;
        return RedirectToAction("Confirm");
    }
    else
        return View(new HomeCreateVM(hc));
}
```

**HomeCreateVM.cshtml:**

```
@model MvcApplication1.ViewModels.HomeCreateVM
<div>
    Name: @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Person.Name)</div>
<div>
    Sex: @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Person.Sex, Model.SelectList, "--Select--")</div>
```

**Create View:**

```
@model MvcApplication1.ViewModels.HomeCreateVM

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>HomeCreateVM</legend>
        @Html.EditorForModel()
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

**Question:**

There is no problem if the POST Create action method accepts a `HomeCreateVM` object as the argument.
However, if I change the POST Create action method argument from `HomeCreateVM` to `Person` (as shown in the code above), `ModelState.IsValid` always returns `false`.

The question is: "Is it possible to pass a ViewModel object to a Create view but only accept a DomainModel object from a POST Create action method?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because your view is strongly typed to the view model your form fields will look like this:

```
<input type="text" name="Person.Name" />
```

and if you want to bind correctly you need to specify the prefix:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Prefix = "Person")]Person hc)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: is it possible not to hard-code the binding prefix in the action method argument?

Comment: @user596314, I understand your concern but unfortunately it is not possible. Only constant values can be passed to attributes.